# How to create a python 2D array with fixed rows but varying columns?

Tags: python, spyder, nested-loops

I'm very new to python. I work with binary files and I'm trying to write a program which reads multiple sets of reading in one go. I've defined ways to get the saved filenames to read them in the next section of the code. The binary file names are saved as "SpecFiles_1" to "SpecFiles_10" where each set of SpecFiles_x are series having multiple objects. ie; for example, SpecFiles_1 has 13 items (binary file names).

Next, I need to run a nested loop in which it accesses the SpecFiles_x one by one and in the inner loop it reads and assigns the binary file to another variable.

```
SampleName_1 = '3_1'
SampleName_2 = '2_1'
Date = '21062023'
WeightHanged_1 = np.arange(14,20.5,0.5)
WeightHanged_2 = np.arange(14,20,1)
Versions = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])


"Getting binary file names"
Wseries_1 = pd.Series(WeightHanged_1).astype(str)
Wseries_2 = pd.Series(WeightHanged_2).astype(str)
Vseries = pd.Series(Versions).astype(str)

"Sample 3_1 filenames"
SpecFiles_1 = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[0]
SpecFiles_2 = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[1]
SpecFiles_3 = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_2 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[2]
SpecFiles_4 = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_2 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[3]
SpecFiles_5 = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[4]
SpecFiles_6 = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[5]

"Sample 2_1 filenames"
SpecFiles_7 = SampleName_2 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[0]
SpecFiles_8 = SampleName_2 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[1]
SpecFiles_9 = SampleName_2 + '_' + Wseries_2 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[2]
SpecFiles_10 = SampleName_2 + '_' + Wseries_2 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[3]

fileId = np.array([])

"vary the range according to the number of SpecFiles"
for x in range(1,11):
    for i in range (0,len('SpecFiles_'+str(x))):
        
        FileId[x,i] = open(SpecFiles_1[0],'rb')
```

This is my code so far. But I'm getting error in the for loop. Could anyone please suggest a better way to assign the read binary files in each set of "SpecFiles_x"? I'm not able to create an empty 2D array and it should be something with fixed rows but varying columns as different sets of "SpecFiles_x" have a different number of binary file names in it.

Comment: When asking such questions, always report the complete error message, which is a hint for troubleshooting.

Comment: There's a lot of issues here. For one, `range (0,len('SpecFiles_'+str(x)))` isn't doing what you think it's doing (it's setting up a range between 0 and the length of the string literal `"SpecFiles_<somenumber>"`. Attempting to dynamically reference a variable is a major antipattern. Using a dictionary would be a much better route to solving.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of changes:

1. Use a dictionary to capture your `SpecFiles_<something>`. This way you can reference the `SpecFiles_<something>` as the string key of your dictionary instead of landing in the "variable variable" or "dynamically reference variables" antipattern that has led you to the current error and confusion.
2. Since you have a dictionary, you can iterate in your inner for loop over the keys instead of having to tease the `len()` out of an iterable.
3. Lastly, using a dictionary once again instead of a two-dim array. It will work the same, but is a more appropriate object for what you are trying to do.

---

```
SampleName_1 = '3_1'
SampleName_2 = '2_1'
Date = '21062023'
WeightHanged_1 = np.arange(14,20.5,0.5)
WeightHanged_2 = np.arange(14,20,1)
Versions = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])


"Getting binary file names"
Wseries_1 = pd.Series(WeightHanged_1).astype(str)
Wseries_2 = pd.Series(WeightHanged_2).astype(str)
Vseries = pd.Series(Versions).astype(str)

"create a dictionary where the key is the specfile variable name and the value is the list being generated by the concatenation with the pd.series"
SpecFileDict={}
SpecFileDict['SpecFiles_1'] = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[0]
SpecFileDict['SpecFiles_2'] = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[1]
SpecFileDict['SpecFiles_3'] = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_2 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[2]
SpecFileDict['SpecFiles_4'] = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_2 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[3]
SpecFileDict['SpecFiles_5'] = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[4]
SpecFileDict['SpecFiles_6'] = SampleName_1 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[5]

"Sample 2_1 filenames"
SpecFileDict['SpecFiles_7'] = SampleName_2 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[0]
SpecFileDict['SpecFiles_8'] = SampleName_2 + '_' + Wseries_1 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[1]
SpecFileDict['SpecFiles_9']= SampleName_2 + '_' + Wseries_2 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[2]
SpecFileDict['SpecFiles_10'] = SampleName_2 + '_' + Wseries_2 + '_' + Date + '_' + Vseries[3]

"vary the range according to the number of SpecFiles"
FileId = {}
for x in range(1,11):
    for specfile in SpecFileDict['SpecFiles_'+str(x)]:         
        entryDict={}
        entryDict[int(specfile[-1])] = open(specfile,'rb')  
        FileId[x] = entryDict
```

Now you can reference the contents of your sample files using syntax like:

```
print(FileId[1][1]) #print the contents of sample file `3_1_20.0_21062023_1`
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want it using numpy, but you have that done using lists - you can have a single column format as save it in variable (which will make the number of columns same), and whenever you want add another row to 2D list just append that variable to 2D list.

```
list_2d = []
# Initializing columns as 0 for a 10 column 2D array
column_format = [0 for _ in range(10)]
# You can have the following done for n number of rows.
list_2d.append(column_format)
```